# Terminology: an $n^{th}$ order ODE that can be written as $n$ 1st order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

If I have an $n^{th}$ order ODE that can be written as $n$ 1st order ODEs, is the original ODE a separable ODE, or is there a different term?

As an example of such an equation, consider:

$$\ddot{x}t^2 + \log(t)\dot{x} = t, t \gt 0$$

We can introduce the variable $v = \dot{x}$ and the above equation can be written as two, first order equations:

(1) $$v = \dot{x}$$
(2) $$\dot{v} = \frac{t - \log(t)v}{t^2}, t \gt 0$$

However, the equation:

$$\log(\ddot{x}) + \sin(\cos(\dot{x} + \ddot{x})) = 0$$

cannot be written as such using a substitution $v = \dot{x}$, (at least, I hope not...)

Comment: Can you add more context here?

Comment: I've edited it to hopefully more fully explain what I'm saying

Comment: The independent variable is the time $t$?

Comment: It is linear. The independent variable is $y$.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, yes.  I meant t (or y, as @KittyL mentioned).  I wanted only a single independent variable.  I'll modify the notation so that it is consistent with "dot" meaning "differentiation wrt time"

Comment: I think your original differential equation must be linear, which is of the form $a_n(t)x^{(n)}+\cdots+a_1(t)\dot{x}+a_0(t)x=b(t)$, and you want to transform it into a linear first order system of differential equations.

Comment: Yes this is the point! The original equation has to be linear, the coefficients not necessary

Comment: Really?  What about an equation like: $\ddot{x}^2 = 4 + \dot{x}$?  It can be separated:  $v = \dot{x}$, $\dot{v} = \sqrt{4 + v}$ can't it?

Comment: For linear equations it works always, for nonlinear sometimes

Comment: Right.  Is there a name for the class of equations for which it works?